# How to do split of column based on a delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i have a column with Values like

```
7AM
10:00AM
11:30AM
12:30PM
9PM
```

Can anyone tell me how achieve this type of output in sql

delimter should be used is ":"

output should be like below for the above input

```
7AM
10
11
12
9PM
```

so if you closely observe the inputs , there may be a case that delimeter wont exist

Comment: Which SQL engine do you use?

Comment: Nothing specific , But i want to know which Method to use. Not able to find any

Comment: The answer totally depends on the engine. SQL dialects differ on MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle,...

Comment: SQL Server to be specific. Thanks